# Multi theme wordpress plugin idea

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have an idea for running multiple wordpress themes at ounce. This might be a good thing to build into a wordpress plugin, if possible. And yes, I might undertake such a task if it isn't ridiculously hard.

(Also, if you are interested in teaming up with me, let me know (leave a comment), I am decent at javascript and php, but not to great, and would love some help!)

This is how I see it working:
Current "set" theme is accessible here: "www.foo.com/"
Second theme accessible here: "www.foo.com/index.php?set_theme=theme2&"
Third theme accessible here: "www.foo.com/index.php?set_theme=THEME_NAME_HERE&"
etc...

This could be used for javascript fall backs. For example, if you go to www.foo.com/?page_id=9 and have javascript turned on, you will hit a javascript redirect to "www.foo.com/index.php?set_theme=THEM_WITH_JAVASCRIPT&page_id=9".

This is how I imagine the plugin code looking/working:

```
   if(isset($_GET['set_theme'])){
       $loadme = cleaned($_GET['set_theme']);       
       if($loadme exists){
          loadtheme($loadme);
       } else {
          //go on as usual, as if this plugin doesnt exist
       }
    } else {
       //go on as usual, as if this plugin doesnt exist
    }
```

And of course, all the links would have to ad ?set_theme=FOOBAR&

So, my main questions are:

1. How and where does Wordpress select the current theme?
2. How/where would you ad this to modify internal links-
   if(isset($_GET['set_theme'])){
      echo "?set_theme=" . $_GET['set_theme'];
   }
3. Do you know of any good websites to point me in the right direction as to how to make WP plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin that was 98% of the way there. Wordpress Theme Switcher Reloaded.

Just changed the ts_get_theme() function as follows:

```
    function ts_get_theme() {
            if (!empty($_GET["wptheme"])) {
                return  $_GET["wptheme"];
            }        else {
                    return '';
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at the [Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher/) plugin to see how that accomplishes this task - should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really need a plugin, just add this to functions.php:

```
        function theme_switcher() {
    if(isset($_GET['theme']) $theme = $_GET['theme'];
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($theme)) {
    $wpdb->prefix
    $queries = “UPDATE “.$wpdb->prefix.”options SET option_value = ‘”.$theme.”‘ WHERE option_name = ‘template’ OR option_name = ‘stylesheet’ OR option_name = ‘current_theme’;”;
    $wpdb->query($query);
    }
    }
add_action('wp_head','switchTheme')
```

then use `mywebsite.com/?theme=myNewTheme` to switch them

Disclaimer: untested!!

Comment: you have a couple errors in there, and you also need to clean $theme before you send it to the DB